# how can i send all the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

i have a component that is inside a page in next js ,i am trying to send some data to the firebase firestore but every time i finish submitting my form the data dont go as it should be it always go missing some info , the scenario is the user enter the apparetement he have then he need to enter the data to the fenetre and placard form after finishing all the form he should click next which send all the data but i find a problem beacuse the data is sending all the info
the data that should go:{

```
    "Appartement 1": {
        "porte_1": {
            "porte_height": "1",
            "porte_width": "1",
            "porte_thickness": "1"
        },
        "placard_1": {
            "placard_height": "1",
            "placard_width": "11",
            "placard_thickness": "1"
        }
    },
    "Appartement 2": {
        "porte_1": {
            "porte_height": "1",
            "porte_width": "1",
            "porte_thickness": "1"
        },
        "placard_1": {
            "placard_height": "1",
            "placard_width": "1",
            "placard_thickness": "1"
        }
    }
}
the data go:
{
    "Appartement 1": {
        "porte_1": {
            "porte_height": "1",
            "porte_width": "1",
            "porte_thickness": "1"
        },
        "placard_1": {
            "placard_height": "1",
            "placard_width": "11",
            "placard_thickness": "1"
        }
    },
    "Appartement 2": {
        "porte_1": {
            "porte_height": "1",
            "porte_width": "1",
            "porte_thickness": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

this the page :

```
import Navbar from "../components/navbar";
import { useState, useEffect, useId } from "react";
import Form from "../components/form";
import { db,auth } from "../config/firebase";
import Placard from "../components/Placard";
import Fenetre from "../components/Fenetre";
import Porte from "../components/Porte";
import Etage from "../components/etage";
import Stepper from "../components/stepper";
import { setDoc, collection, doc,addDoc,getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import handleNext from "../lib/handleNext"; 


export default function ApparetementsForm() {
     const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState("Porte");
     const[mainCount,setmainCount]=useState(1)
     const[mainFormdata,setmainFormdata]=useState({})
     
     const router = useRouter();
     const { value1, value2 } = router.query;


     const [userId, setuserId] = useState('');
     useEffect(() => {
      // Check if the user is logged in
       const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       if (user) {
           setuserId(user.uid); // Set the user's email in state
           Cookies.set('uid', user.uid)

           }
        });

    return () => unsubscribe(); // Cleanup the event listener
  }, []);
 

const navigateToPlacard = () => {
  if(activeComponent==='Porte'){setActiveComponent('Placard')}
};
const navigateToPort = () => {
  if(activeComponent==='Placard'){
    setActiveComponent('Porte')
    if(parseInt(mainCount)<parseInt(value1))
    {
      setmainCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('main formdata',mainFormdata);
      handleNext(mainFormdata,userId);
      router.push('http://localhost:3000/Apparetment')
    }
   
  }
};
// useEffect(() => {
//   console.log('mainFormdata updated:', mainFormdata);
//   console.log(mainCount,value1);
//   if(parseInt(mainCount)>parseInt(value1))
//   {

//    handleNext(mainFormdata,userId);
//     console.log('done');
//     console.log(mainFormdata);
//   }
// }, [mainFormdata]);

  return (
     <>
      <Navbar />
      <div>
       
         {activeComponent === "Porte" && <Porte onNext={handleNext}
          apparetementNumber={parseInt(value1)} floorNumber={value2} mainCount={mainCount} mainFormdata={mainFormdata}   setmainFormdata={setmainFormdata}  navigateToPlacard={navigateToPlacard}  />}
         {activeComponent === "Placard" && <Placard onNext={handleNext}
          apparetementNumber={parseInt(value1)} floorNumber={value2} mainCount={mainCount} mainFormdata={mainFormdata}   setmainFormdata={setmainFormdata} navigateToPort={navigateToPort}  />}
    </div>
     
   
    </>
  )
}
```

this the component placard :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db, auth } from "../config/firebase";
import { setDoc, collection, doc, addDoc, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import Form from "../components/form";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import Porte from "./Porte";
import handleNext from "../lib/handleNext";



export default function Placard({ onNext, apparetementNumber, floorNumber,mainCount,navigateToPort, setmainFormdata,mainFormdata }) {
  // const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState("Placard");
  
  const [count, setCount] = useState(mainCount);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(mainFormdata);
  const [userId, setuserId] = useState('');
  const dataForm = ['height', 'width', 'thickness', 'Appartement','Placard'];
  
  // const newCount=0;

  var show = false;
  if (Object.keys(formData).length !== 0) {
    show = true;
  }


  const handleDeleteForm = (appartementNumber, porteIndex) => {
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const updatedFormData = { ...prevFormData };
      const appartementKey = `Appartement ${appartementNumber}`;
      const currentAppartement = updatedFormData[appartementKey];

      if (currentAppartement) {
        delete currentAppartement[`placard_${porteIndex}`];
      }

      return updatedFormData;
    });
  };


  const handleInputChange = (appartementNumber, placardIndex, type, value) => {
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      toast.error('Please enter a number', {
        style: {
          backgroundColor: '#b54343',
          color: '#000000',
        },
      });
      return;
    }
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const updatedFormData = { ...prevFormData };

      const appartementKey = `Appartement ${appartementNumber}`;
      const currentAppartement = { ...updatedFormData[appartementKey] };

      const currentplacard = {
        ...currentAppartement[`placard_${placardIndex}`],
        [`placard_${type}`]: value,
      };

      currentAppartement[`placard_${placardIndex}`] = currentplacard;

      updatedFormData[appartementKey] = currentAppartement;

      return updatedFormData;
    });
  };


  const handleNextClick = () => {
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      const value = inputs[i].value;
      if (value === '') {
        toast.error('Please fill all fields', {
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#b54343',
            color: '#000000',
          },
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
          inputs[i].style.borderColor = '';
        }, 5000);
  
        return;
      }
      // Validate the input value as a number
      if (isNaN(value)) {
        inputs[i].style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        inputs[i].style.borderColor = 'red';
        toast.error('Please enter a number', {
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#b54343',
            color: '#000000',
          },
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
          inputs[i].style.borderColor = '';
        }, 5000);
  
        return;
      }
    }
  
    // Proceed to the next step if all input values are numbers
    toast.success('All doors are filled', {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#368039',
        color: '#FFF',
      },
    });
    console.log('Data is valid. Proceed to the next step');
  
    const updatedFormData = { ...formData };
  
    const appartementKey = `Appartement ${count}`;
    const currentAppartement = { ...updatedFormData[appartementKey] };
  
    // Loop through the inputs and add their values to the current apartment
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      const input = inputs[i];
      const type = input.getAttribute('id').split('_')[0];
      const placardIndex = input.getAttribute('id').split('_')[2];
      const value = input.value;
  
      const currentplacard = {
        ...currentAppartement[`placard_${placardIndex}`],
        [`placard_${type}`]: value,
      };
  
      currentAppartement[`placard_${placardIndex}`] = currentplacard;
    }
  
    updatedFormData[appartementKey] = currentAppartement;
    
    // setFormData(updatedFormData);
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
    {
       inputs[i].value='';
    }
    
      
      console.log(formData);
       navigateToPort();
      
          setmainFormdata(updatedFormData)
       
      
      
      
      

  };
  
  return (
    <>
   
  
  <div>
  Placard
          <Form
            number={count}
            handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
            handleDeleteForm={handleDeleteForm}
            data={dataForm}
          />
          <div className="flex justify-center mt-16">
            <div className="flex justify-start">
              <button
                type="Submit"
                onClick={handleNextClick}
                className="focus:outline-none text-white bg-green-700 hover:bg-green-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-green-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-14 py-2.5 mr-4 mb-2 dark:bg-green-600 dark:hover:bg-green-700 dark:focus:ring-green-800 text-center"
              >
                Next
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      <ToastContainer position="bottom-right" />
    </>
  );
  
}
```

please help me in this i suppose it is a problem with the async?